# How to replace all columns in matrix with NA based on variable in another dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a large adjacency matrix and a dataframe with a variable 'missing'. I need to replace all rows in the matrix with NA, for which 'missing' = TRUE (rows match between matrix and dataframe).

Example:
I have: matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0
```

and dataframe

```
  ID missing
1  1   FALSE
2  2   FALSE
3  3    TRUE
```

I need: matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]   NA    NA    NA
```

Reproducible data:

```
m1.data <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 )
m1 <- matrix(m1.data, nrow = 3)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
                missing = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Hope that someone can help! Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can extract the `missing` column and use that as the row index in `m1` and assign it to `NA`

```
m1[df$missing,] <- NA
```

-output

```
> m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

---

Or we may do

```
> NA^(df$missing) * m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: What are you doing with `^`

Comment: The `NA^` changes the TRUE values to NA and FALSE to 1

Comment: @TarJae It is a hacky way i.e for `^` if you use any other value other than 0, it returns NA i.e. `NA^1` `NA^2`, `NA^0`.  Since, `TRUE` -> `1`, it returns the NA

Answer (score 3):

With `which` we could get the Id for the missing and assing a `NA` to `m1` it is similar to akrun's approach `m1[df$missing,] <- NA`

```
m1[which(df$missing==TRUE),] <- NA
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
```